# How to fill the data or access a 3-dimensional vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, neural-network

I am implementing a 2-Dimensional Neuron Network on Windows, Visual Studio 2015.

[image: 2-D Neuron Network]

Picture is from Dave Miller blog https://github.com/davidrmiller/neural2d#2D

I have a topology variable, which is the structure of the network => therefore it's the 3-dimensional vector of Neurons exactly like the picture above.

my topology is a vector of Layers:

```
typedef vector<vector<Neuron>> Layer; // this is written outside main()
vector<Layer> topology;               // this is within main()
```

then, in my main(), I create the test topology with an example layers to test my Net class constructor:

```
int main()
{
// test topology {3x3,2x2,2}
vector<Layer> topology;
Layer L0 [3][3]; 
Layer L1 [2][2]; 
Layer L2 [1][2]; 

topology.push_back(L0);
topology.push_back(L1);
topology.push_back(L2);


Net myNet(topology); // create the network


return 0;
}
```

To test my Net constructor, I will {cout} the letter 'k' on each creation of a new Neuron:

```
class Net
{
 public:
 Net(vector<Layer> topology) // constructor
 {
    // Create the Layers and fill it with neurons
    for (int LayersNumber = 0; LayersNumber < topology.size(); LayersNumber++)  //(0 is the input layer, last is output, rest are the hidden)
    {
        m_layers.push_back(Layer()); // add a 2-d layer

        for (int NeuronRow = 0; NeuronRow < topology[LayersNumber].size(); NeuronRow++) // fill the layer with Neurons
        {
            m_layers.back().push_back(vector<Neuron>(0)); // add a vector of Neurons on the new 2-d layer (using .back())

            for (int NeuronColumn = 0; NeuronColumn <= topology[LayersNumber][NeuronRow].size(); NeuronColumn++) // <= for the Bias Neuron
            {
                m_layers[LayersNumber].back().push_back(Neuron()); // add a Neuron
            // m_layers[LayerNum][NeuronRow]{NeuronColumn]

                cout << "K" << endl; // display test

            }
        }

    }

};
```

For some reason I have an error in my main() on the .push_back function calls. It says arguments don't match the argument type. I couldn't figure it out.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of coping with std vector ; IMHO you should use a data structure designed for multi dimensions. A good example presented in cppconf2015: https://youtu.be/CPPX4kwqh80  ; you can find the git hub link in video's description.

Answer (score 0):

Your vector type is Layer but your variable type is Layer[][] so it don't match. You can instead change your vector type to `std::array`

```
std::vector<std::array<Layer, 12> >
```

and change your array to `std::array` or use vector inside vector

```
std::vector<std::vector<Layer> > multiLayer;
```